# nil can't be coerced into BigDecimal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

hi guys im playing with RoR with the environment of rails 3 ruby 1.9
i got stuck in

> nil can't be coerced into BigDecimal

error

i need to get the total cost of the products inside the cart
i know where the problem is(i think) but i almost did every thing

cart/show.html.rb

```
<div class="cart_title" >Your Cart</div>
    <table>
        <% for item in @cart.line_items %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= item.quantity %>&times;</td>
        <td><%= item.product.title %></td>
    <td class="item_price" ><%= number_to_currency(item.total_price) %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
        <tr class="total_line" >
        <td colspan="2" >Total</td>
        <td class="total_cell" ><%= number_to_currency(@cart.total_price) %></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
        <%= button_to 'Empty cart', @cart, :method => :delete,
        :confirm => 'Are you sure?' %>
```

model/line_item.rb

```
  def total_price
    line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.total_price }
  end
```

model/cart.rb

```
 def total_price
    product.price  * quantity
  end
```

my second option is

```
def total_price
     if product.price 
       product.price * quantity
     else
       product.price = "0.0".to_d
     end
   end
```

but still this wont work

thanks more power to us!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `cart.rb` model:

```
def total_price
  product.price  * quantity
end
```

You don't have a single product in your cart; you have *many* products in your cart. You'll need to sum all the prices from all the *line items* in your cart. (You want to use the line items, rather than the products directly, in case the product prices change after the client has committed to buying products at the old price.)

How you'll fix this depends upon the details of your models but you'll be looking for something like this:

```
def total_price
    line_items.to_a.each(&:total_price).sum
end
```

This will run the `total_price` method on every item in your `line_items` collection, build a list of them all, and then `sum` the list.

Comment: how can i do that? can you give me a example im new in RoR thanks :)